# How to create a new record to a junction table

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I need to post to a junction table Entity Framework generated(CustomerEmployeeJobs). Every Job can have multiple Customer Employees. Every Job must have a CustomerEmployee PM, CustomerEmployee Account, CustomerEmployee Admin and a CustomerEmployee Superintendent.Right now those are defined with the CustomerEmployeeRole property. When I create a new Job I have select boxes that display the Customer Employees with there appropriate title. So how do I make this POST? I assumed this relationship would be a many-to-many. The Junction table has a JobId and CustomerEmployeeId columns. So It seems like that is correct. I can manually add the same JobId with multiple CustomerEmployeeId's. But how do i do that through the actual application?  Here is a plunkr of what the New Job Modal looks like. Would it be better if I changed how I store the CustomerEmployee titles? Instead of "string" CustomerEmployeeRole it could be booleans,  "bool" CustomerEmployeeIsPM, CustomerEmployeeIsAdmin, etc....
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5jpvCe38mksrm0fnkEHn?p=preview)

```
public class Job
{
    //job
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public int? JobNumber { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CustomerEmployee> CustomerEmployees { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerEmployee
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeeLastName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeeRole { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}

// POST api/<controller>
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostnewJob([FromBody]JobViewModel newJob)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var job = new Job();

            Mapper.CreateMap<JobViewModel, Job>();
            Mapper.Map(newJob, job);

            context.Jobs.Add(job);

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtRoute("JobApi", new { job.JobId }, job);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your model is not correct. What you say is:

- Your job has exactly 1 customerPM and exactly 1 CustomerSuperintendent
- Your CustomerPM can have multiple jobs as well as your CustomerSuperintendent

So your in between your CustomerEmployee table and your Job table there is no need for a junction table. Your Job table should just have 2 foreign keys to the CustomerEmployee table

Your model will then look like this I suppose:

```
public class Job
{
    //job
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public int? JobNumber { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerPMId")] 
    public CustomerEmployee CustomerPM { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerSuperintendentId")]        
    public CustomerEmployee CustomerSuperintendent { get; set; }
}
```

And allthough it is not part of your question and therefore offtopic, but I want to mention: Be very carefull with automapper in the direction your using it! The otherway around is perfect, but from your DTO to the ef model, IMO Don't do it! Your MVC model will be likely to change depending on different needs in your view and then you'll need configuration of automapper to correct which is probably not worth the trouble if you keep your entities nice and small, like you have own.

Comment: How does it know that those are foreign keys? Can you please edit my post to the way it should be set.

Comment: I'm not a fan nor an expert on entity framework using code first. Nevertheless, normally EF would find your foreign keys automagically based on your navigation properties. When you have more than one reference, like now, this must be configured. See this link for documentation: [EF Code First Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)

Comment: It seems to be as simple as adding a DataAnnotations Attribute to the navigation property, see my edit in the code.

Comment: k, I'm not following. The junction table is working as is. my issue is how do i create a new job? I dont see how I can have Foreign Keys in the Job class if they dont exist in the CustomerEmployee Class. I think I didn't explain it as well as I should. let me add some more information to post

Comment: You now describe 4 CustomerEmployee's. Is that the model? Or could it be that this be 3 or 6 for another job? If 4 is what it is, my answer still applies, apart that you need 4 foreign keys instead of 2 to the CustomerEmployee table.

Comment: Much easier than I thought. thanks! It took me a little while to wrap my head around it!